# How to create a sequence of times with different intervals based on a start time

Tags: r

I want to generate a sequence of times based on a starting time, with intervals of first 15 minutes, then a repeat of an interval of 30 minutes and 4x 20 minutes. I'm very new to R, so don't really know where to start with this.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're after. i.e. what should the sequence look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_time <- "2019-08-13 12:00"

intervals <- c(0, 15, 30, rep(20,4))

seconds <- cumsum(intervals)*60

lapply(seconds, function(x)strptime(start_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + x) 

# [[1]]
# [1] "2019-08-13 12:00:00 +08"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2019-08-13 12:15:00 +08"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "2019-08-13 12:45:00 +08"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "2019-08-13 13:05:00 +08"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "2019-08-13 13:25:00 +08"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "2019-08-13 13:45:00 +08"
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] "2019-08-13 14:05:00 +08"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with date and time, the answer by @Adam Quek is OK. Alternatively if you want to work with times only, you can use the "times" class found in the chron package.
For example, you can set your starting time to 9 o’clock by typing:

```
starting<-times("09:00:00")
```

Then you can add 15 minutes by:

```
starting+times("00:15:00")
[1] 09:15:00
```

You can also sum a fraction with the number of minutes you want to add in the numerator and the number of minutes in one day (60*24=1440) in the denominator

```
starting+15/1440
[1] 09:15:00
```

Therefore, you can create your sequence by:

```
minutesToAdd<-c(0,15,30,rep(20,4))
starting + cumsum(minutesToAdd/1440)
[1] 09:00:00 09:15:00 09:45:00 10:05:00 10:25:00 10:45:00 11:05:00
```